# Can I deploy to and debug on Glassfish v2 using Eclipse Kepler?

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

I'm trying to make the switch to Eclipse. I am using the most recent release (Kepler). It looks like the plugins which let me deploy to Glassfish only support versions 3 and 4 on Kepler. Is there any way to deploy and debug on Glassfish version 2 from Kepler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You will need to stay with Juno until you are able to move to a newer version of GlassFish. The last version with GlassFish v2 support is available at the following location:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/oepe-download-121121-1918582.html

Comment: Double checking, Juno is 4.2 and Kepler is 4.3 right? So my Eclipse experience won't vary much.

Comment: Yes, the experience will be pretty similar. The big thing in Kepler is Java EE 7 support, but you can't use that anyway with GF v2. Note that latest version for Juno also doesn't have GF v2 support, so you will need to use the plugin repository provided with OEPE 12.1.1.2.1 release.